# finding the copyright character with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i am a newbee to Beautifulsoup...here's my challenge:

i have a list of 3000 urls that i am using to find the name of the company. what i want to do is:

1. scrape the home page
2. search for the © character
3. if © is found, scrape the content for that p element (e.g. *site design / logo © 2018 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under cc by-sa 3.0 with attribution required. rev 2018.9.22.31657*)

this seems simple, but all of the tutorials that i've read assume a use case where multiple content elements are being scraped from a **single url**, so it's possible to search based on the tags, attributes, etc. in my example, i won't be able to inspect the html of each website, so i need to search for a character instead.

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show some sample URLs and what the output should be for them.

Comment: @MartinEvans - here are some examples: 

  http://google.com -> Google Inc
  http://apple.com -> Apple Inc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should get you started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

for url in ['http://www.apple.com/', 'http://www.google.com', 'http://www.stackoverflow.com/']:
    html = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

    for text in soup.stripped_strings:
        if '©' in text:
            text = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', text)  # condense any whitespace
            print(f'"{url}"  {text}')
```

Which would display:

```
"http://www.apple.com/"  Copyright © 2018 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
"http://www.google.com"  © 2018 -
"http://www.stackoverflow.com/"  site design / logo © 2018 Stack Exchange Inc; user contributions licensed under
```

Tested using Python 3.6.6

Comment: thanks @Martin Evans! the critical piece of info was ".stripped_strings"